# dijkstra's algorithm in time O(k|V|+|E|)

Tags: algorithm, graph, distance, minimum

I have to calculate the minimum distance from a source node 's' for undirected and connected graphs G = (V, E) with weights on the arcs belonging to the set { 1, 2, . . . , K }, where k is a fixed integer . Implement Dijkstra's algorithm taking advantage of the peculiarity of these graphs so that the minimum distances to be calculated in O ( k | V | + | E |). I've no idea how to solve this problem....so i don't need the specific code , but I need an algorithmic idea.

Comment: I'd try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you familiar with the original Dijkstra algorithm ?

Comment: yes , i'm familiar with  Dijkastra's algorithm

Comment: I have the feeling that the "tweak" resides in the choice of the data structure used to store the vertices to be visited (a binary heap in most cases) ... But I can't see which one to use

Comment: One idea is to split an edge of weight 'i' into 'i' edges of weight 1. Then the resulting graph shall be un-weighted and you can conduct a simple BFS on it. Not sure if it would satisfy the complexity requirements though. IMO it shall become O(k*E + V).

Comment: I solved it , LOG |E| in dijkastra's algorithm is caused by update of heap ,but  in this case i don't need the heap beacause the weights on the arcs is limited ...so it's sufficient do a loop from 1 to k and adding the nodes that have weight 1 to nodes that have weight k , of course , using the idea of dijkastra. The complexity of this loop is O(k|V|) .

Comment: Could you make that an answer and accept it?